# ruby 2.1.2 messes up Time.now.utc in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, time, production, ruby-2.1

I am having a strange issue with `Time.now.utc` in my `production` environment. The `development` environment is giving the correct values. I am using `ruby-2.1.2-p95` and `rails 4.0.0` for both the environments. The environments of my `production` and `development` are similar with no changes in the `Time` class.

Production Environment:

```
2.1.2 :001 > Time.now
 => 2016-05-20 18:16:24 +0200
2.1.2 :002 > Time.now.zone
 => "CEST"
```

Development Environment:

```
2.1.2 :012 > Time.now
 => 2016-05-20 16:16:24 +0200
2.1.2 :013 > Time.now.zone
 => "CEST"
```

As you can see from above, the time zones are same but the times in these different environments are different. Can anyone please point out where the error might be coming from? If you need further information please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue so as rails best practices suggested , Used `Time.zone.now` instead of `Time.now`

http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/2014/10/22/use-time-zone-now-instead-of-time-now/

I hope it fixes for you too